# Smart Phone ! Iphone | Reading the device phone number HTTP etc

Tags: iphone

Does anyone know if one of these devices connect to the web whether their phone number can be read from a header or some other means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phone numbers don't go in HTTP headers. Your IP address will be visible to the web server, but that is it.

Edit:
Ah, I see you *want* to get the phone number. This is a privacy issue for many people and the consensus is that the minor inconvenience of having to explicitly enter a phone number is worth the peace of mind that no one is stealing it.

What you can do is ask the user for their number, and store it along with the phone's UDID in a database. Next time your app connects to your server, you can send it the phone's UDID and look up the number from that.

Comment: With such devices do they have fixed ips - so if for example such a device hits my site i can ask the user their number - then log it to their ip - of course i understand i could just log the number to their user account - but i want to be device specific incase the user has more than one device, per account login.

Comment: I should add:
Using the above method would enable my site to identify the device as it hits my sever. I hope that makes sense?

Comment: Any solution that would allow me to id the phone and its number? say with user asist of first visit to site? cookie?

Comment: See my edit for how to remember this info after the first visit.

Comment: David - Thanks for this its very helpful - so can i recap.
If i have a website and a mobile device connects/views if from the browser can i get the device UDID?
As you say if i can then of course i can store it - ask for their number and then its a simple lookup antilogarithm.

Comment: You can get it, but only from an actual program, not just from headers. You could however, write a rather small app that essentially sends this info, and displays a webpage. If you don't want to do this, then you should probably have users create accounts on your site and track them with cookies as you said.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not passed across.